# Neo4j - Need to aggregate values on different relationships between same pair of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to multiply the properties on two different relationships between same pair of nodes and **SUM()** it,then **ORDER BY** the pairs based on the value.
Ex:

```
Let (X:amps)-[:coocr{val:1}]->b
    (X:amps)-[:jacc{dist:2}]->b
    (X:amps)-[:coocr{val:2}]->c
    (X:amps)-[:jacc{dist:3}]->c
    (X:amps)-[:coocr]->d
    (X:amps)-[:jacc{dist:4}]->d
    (Y:amps)-[:coocr{val:2}]->b
    (Y:amps)-[:jacc{dist:3}]->b
    (Y:amps)-[:coocr{val:1}]->c
    (Y:amps)-[:jacc{dist:4}]->c
    (Y:amps)-[:coocr{val:4}]->d
    (Y:amps)-[:jacc{dist:3}]->d
```

Now, 
    1) Each node b,c,d has two relationships with X,Y, which are multiplies and          added pair wise
    2)Return the highest value

My attempt to the prob:

```
WITH [b,c,d] AS words                                                                
MATCH (i:amps) 
MATCH n where n.word in words
MATCH p=(i-[r:jaccard]->(n)) with i,r.dist as dist UNWIND dist as distances
MATCH q=(i-[s:coocr]->(n)) with distances,i,s.val as co UNWIND co as coocr
WITH i, SUM(distances*coocr) AS agg
RETURN i,agg ORDER BY agg DESC
```

My aggragate function has to work like:

```
X-[]->b has[jaccard,coocr] , so, jacc.dist*coocr.val = 1*2 =2
X-[]->c has[jaccard,coocr] , so, jacc.dist*coocr.val = 2*3 =6
X-[]->d has[jaccard,] , so, jacc.dist*null = null*2 =0
                                                    --------------
                                                      sum  = 8
                                                    --------------

Y-[]->b has[jaccard,coocr] , so, jacc.dist*coocr.val = 4*2 =8
Y-[]->c has[jaccard,coocr] , so, jacc.dist*coocr.val = 1*3 =3
Y-[]->d has[jaccard,coocr] , so, jacc.dist*coocr.val = 4*4 =16
                                                    --------------
                                                      sum  = 27
                                                    --------------
```

Then returning these aggregate orderly.

My query returning the aggregates, which are only products, not the whole sum.
Need to achieve the whose sum.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you are trying to calculate. What is the expected result regarding the above dataset?

Comment: Will Update the question

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
MATCH (a:amps)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[coocr:coocr]-(n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[jacc:jacc]-(n)
WITH a, COALESCE(coocr.val, 0) AS val, COALESCE(jacc.dist, 0) AS dist
RETURN a, SUM(val * dist) AS agg
ORDER BY agg DESC
```

Comment: Not concerned with OPTIONAL MATCH. Issue is aggregating all n relationship values(coocr*jacc) of a.

Comment: aggregation happens per node `a`.  The optional match just returns nul valuesl if there is no such relationship

Comment: Yeah, if there is no relationship (like your case between `X` and `d`) then `OPTIONAL MATCH` returns `NULL`.  `COALESCE` gives you the first non-`NULL` value out of it's arguments, so that makes it default to `0` if there was no relationship.  As Michael said, it should aggregate by `a` because in Cypher any `RETURN` columns with non-aggregate functions are used as the grouping values

Comment: Yeah it helped a lot. But a small extension to your suggestion resolved my problem. I will post my answer below. Thankyou Brian..

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ["best", "high", "quality","4k"] AS words                                                                
MATCH (i:amps) 
MATCH n where n.word in words
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(i-[r:jaccard]->(n)) with n,i,COALESCE(r.dist, 0)  as distances
OPTIONAL MATCH q=(i-[s:coocr]->(n)) with distances,n,i,COALESCE(s.val, 0) AS  coocr
WITH i,n,distances,coocr, (distances*coocr) AS agg
WITH i,SUM(agg) AS agg
RETURN i,agg
```

Aggregation function,in last but one line resolved the problem. Thanks for the suggestion Brain.